# Docker COPY doesn't work

Tags: docker, build, devops

fellows I need help with Docker!

```
#DockerfileCron    
FROM node:6

RUN mkdir /www
COPY . /www

WORKDIR /www

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y cron

CMD ["cron", "-f"]
```

When I build an image based on this Dockerfile, the command `COPY` just copy Dockerfile and ignore all other files in the folder.

```
# construção das imagens
docker build -t job/job_cronjob - < DockerfileCron

# executa o cron
docker run -d \
        --name job_cronjob job/job_cronjob
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: do you have a .dockerignore? see https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `docker build -t job/job_cronjob - < DockerfileCron`

Problem: "This will read a Dockerfile from STDIN without context. Due to the lack of a context, no contents of any local directory will be sent to the Docker daemon. Since there is no context, a Dockerfile ADD only works if it refers to a remote URL." - https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#build-with--

**Solution: Use `-f` flag for specifying Dockerfile:**

`docker build -t job/job_cronjob -f DockerfileCron .`

Comment: @JhonDoe no problem. Here is part of documentation where you could find it yourself: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#build-with--